# text-align: justify and images

Tags: css

I have a list of images (not in a list, but could be if that might solve the problem) that I want to fill the whole width of a div. I've tried the code at the bottom, and while it does justify any text in the p tag it doesn't do the same for images. How can I get it to evenly space the images across the full width of the div?

```
<div>
  <p>
    <img src="image1.png" alt="foo" />
    <img src="image2.png" alt="foo" />
    <img src="image3.png" alt="foo" />
    <img src="image4.png" alt="foo" />
    <img src="image5.png" alt="foo" />
  </p>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div { width: 30em; }
p { text-align: justify; }
```

Comment: Forgot to add: The number of images isn't fixed, so I want a solution that doesn't rely on knowing how many there will be.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, If your'e willing to use javascript, the answer I provided adjusts for any number of images.

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way to make it is :

```css
.justify-image{ text-align: justify;}
.justify-image img{display:inline-block;}
.justify-image:after{content:""; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 0;}
```

```html
<p class="justify-image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="my img">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="my img">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="my img">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="my img">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="my img">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x40" alt="my img">

</p>
```

1. You need a container with **`text-align:justify;`** (a `<p>` paragraph in this case.)
 2. Your images need to be **`display:inline-block;`** else they will not interact as "text" (in justify text last line is not affected you need to add one to make it works.)
 3. You need a line of "text" under your images for justifying to apply, with pseudo-element you can achieve it easily by creating a ***`:after`**.

**`*:after`** :
Don't forget **`content:"";`**. Without it, it will not appear. In my example I've used an **`inline-block`** with **`width:100%`**. It will always break the line after the content in my paragraph.

Happy coding ! :)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Worked for me, but make sure there are no other elements using the `:after` feature

Comment: Thanks! also it seems to work the same, with or without `inline-block`

Answer (score 7):

Because no one mention in the previous answers. Nowadays (2017) and for awhile ago you can use `CSS3 flexbox`, by applying the property `justify-content:space-between`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="foo" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="foo" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="foo" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="foo" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="foo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a more updated answer! (2021 here, lol). Upvoting for visibility.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Images are displayed inline so you might as well use the text-align:justify css property to align your images with css. As others suggest, if you want to justify the final row you will have to insert some sort or blank image that takes up the full width at the end of your image list.

See http://fiddle.jshell.net/ewv6K/show/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>
    Justified Images example
</title>
<style>
    body {
        text-align:center;
    }
    #container {
        width:800px;
        text-align:justify;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    #force {
        width:100%;
        height:0px;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/AfricanWildCat.jpg/220px-AfricanWildCat.jpg" alt="cat 1">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/WhiteCat.jpg/220px-WhiteCat.jpg" alt="cat 2">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Ojo_de_gata_trim.jpg/220px-Ojo_de_gata_trim.jpg" alt="cat 3">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Scheme_cat_anatomy-en.svg/220px-Scheme_cat_anatomy-en.svg.png" alt="cat 4">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg/220px-Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg" alt="cat 5">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Listen%2C_do_you_want_to_know_a_secret.jpg/220px-Listen%2C_do_you_want_to_know_a_secret.jpg" alt="cat 6">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/AfricanWildCat.jpg/220px-AfricanWildCat.jpg" alt="cat 1">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/WhiteCat.jpg/220px-WhiteCat.jpg" alt="cat 2">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Ojo_de_gata_trim.jpg/220px-Ojo_de_gata_trim.jpg" alt="cat 3">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Scheme_cat_anatomy-en.svg/220px-Scheme_cat_anatomy-en.svg.png" alt="cat 4">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg/220px-Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg" alt="cat 5">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Listen%2C_do_you_want_to_know_a_secret.jpg/220px-Listen%2C_do_you_want_to_know_a_secret.jpg" alt="cat 6">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/AfricanWildCat.jpg/220px-AfricanWildCat.jpg" alt="cat 1">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/WhiteCat.jpg/220px-WhiteCat.jpg" alt="cat 2">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Ojo_de_gata_trim.jpg/220px-Ojo_de_gata_trim.jpg" alt="cat 3">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Scheme_cat_anatomy-en.svg/220px-Scheme_cat_anatomy-en.svg.png" alt="cat 4">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg/220px-Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg" alt="cat 5">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Listen%2C_do_you_want_to_know_a_secret.jpg/220px-Listen%2C_do_you_want_to_know_a_secret.jpg" alt="cat 6">
    <!-- Force the last row to be justifed - use a blank image here, not a real one like I have -->
    <img id="force" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg/220px-Olhos_de_um_gato-3.jpg" alt="end">
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2):

In justified text, the last line of text in a paragraph is not expanded to fill the whole width. So to make the inline images spread out you need enough content to pull the paragraph out to two or more lines, eg.:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <img src="image1.png" alt="foo" />
        <img src="image2.png" alt="foo" />
        <img src="image3.png" alt="foo" />
        <img src="image4.png" alt="foo" />
        <img src="image5.png" alt="foo" />
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </p>
</div>
```

(or some other equally-ugly but less-visible version involving `&nbsp;`.) This is a bit of a nasty hack.

Comment: You can use `<span style="visibility:hidden">&nbsp;&nbsp;...</span>`

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is way out of date but just thought I'd add a simple solution.
`text-align: justify` will only work if there is more than one line (if you use this on a paragraph of text, you will see that the last line does not justify). This little jQuery extention will add an invisible element to the element you are trying to justify and thus, your images will be evenly spread:

```
$.fn.justify = function() {
 $(this).css("text-align", "justify");
 $(this).append("<span style='display: inline-block;visibility: hidden;width:100%'></span>");
}
```

Then all you need to do is call:

```
$("#your-element").justify();
```

Answer (score 0):

This javascript will spread the images over the div from the middleand to the sides:

```
var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
var imageList = container.getElementsByTagName("img");

var totalWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var sliceWidth = totalWidth/imageList.length;

for( i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++)
{
  var totalMargin = sliceWidth - imageList[i].offsetWidth;
  var margin =  totalMargin / 2;

  imageList[i].style.margin = "0px " + margin + "px 0px " + margin + "px"
}
```

The script asume a couple of things;

1. There must be an ID of the div (imageContainer)
2. All the images must have the same width
3. For my convinience I only tested in IE7, there are things that I'm not sure about such as "offsetWidth" that may be different in Firefox etc. but this is mostly for you to get the concept of the script.

You could of course add support for variable image widths and so forth, but that wasn't really in the scope here.

This script will distribute the images evenly if you add or remove images, ofcourse to a limit. If the total width of the images is greater than the width of the div, there will be wrapping.

Hope it helps!

Comment: use JS only after trying to layout images via CSS, don't rely on JS only!

Comment: This is a nice solution!. 
But works only if there is ONE line of images.
Can this be extended to multi-line cases too ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- not elegant -->
    <div style="color:backgroundcolor">
      <p>
       <img src="image1.png" alt="foo" 
       /><em>.</em>
       <img src="image2.png" alt="foo"
       /><em>.</em>
       <img src="image3.png" alt="foo"
       /><em>.</em>
       <img src="image4.png" alt="foo"
       /><em>.</em>
       <img src="image5.png" alt="foo" />
      </p>
     </div>

    My CSS:

    div { width: 30em; }
    p { text-align: justify; }
```