# Justify images CSS

Tags: html, css, justify

I want to justify 3 images, I have never done this before so I have no clue how to do it.
Now I Googled a bit and found the property "justify", but I saw it only works for Text ( correct me if i'm wrong. )

But I tried the following.

**HTML**

```
        <ul>
            <li><img class="uspIconOntwerp" src="images/ontwerp-icon.png" /><div class="uspText">Ontwerp</div></li>
            <li><img class="uspIconRealisatie" src="images/realisatie-icon.png" /><div class="uspText">Realisatie</div></li>
            <li><img class="uspIconPrijs" src="images/prijs-icon.png" /><div class="uspText">Betaalbare prijs</div></li>
        </ul>
```

**And my css**

```
    ul
{
        text-align: justify;
}
```

But this doesn't work (ofcourse).

Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Comment: To do what? Align text with image?

Comment: And I just googled the title and found: [text-align: justify and images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464934/text-align-justify-and-images). Not sure if it meets your needs though.

Comment: I want to justify images horizontally in the full with of my website

Comment: You mean something like that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/70zyqpL7/1/) ?

Comment: I mean something like this. http://i.imgur.com/slH3qPh.png the images has to spread horizontally over the whole page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `justify` property works as do in the alignment of texts you will need to make the `li` items `inline-block` elements. Try this:

```
ul {
  text-align: justify;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
ul {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="Grid">
  <li>
    <img class="uspIconOntwerp" src="images/ontwerp-icon.png" />
    <div class="uspText">Ontwerp</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="uspIconRealisatie" src="images/realisatie-icon.png" />
    <div class="uspText">Realisatie</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="uspIconPrijs" src="images/prijs-icon.png" />
    <div class="uspText">Betaalbare prijs</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Note that you will need that `after` pseudo-element in order to make that line of items work as an entire one not the last on some justified content.

Comment: Ah thanks! But it doesn't work when i make my width 75%

Comment: @ThijsKempers why not? Recreate that example on jsfiddle please